# Support for RTL pdf reading on tables using JasperReports framework

Tags: jasper-reports, right-to-left, export-to-pdf

I am tring to build an accessible for the hard of seeing pdf file using JasperReports java framework
There is an option of adding accessable tags to tables, but it looks like the reading is done from left to right
This is not what I need, since this is a hebrew (rtl language) pdf
I see that there is support for RTL crosstab elements in JasperReport, but I didn't see any for tables
What would you suggest as the best way to have the accessable rtl support on pdf tables?

Tried to use chat gpt, unfortunately it gave me all kind of properies to use that were not recognized by Jasper
I tried to reorder the tables rows after having jasper calculate there positions, but that caused some of the rows not to be read properly

Comment: If you want to downgrade a question you can at least give a reason' maybe next time I'll know what not to do

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by overriding the exportFrame(JRPrintFrame frame) and exportElements(Collection elements) methods in JRPdfExporter of the JasperReports framework

In exportFrame(JRPrintFrame frame) I chacked if we are in table using the "net.sf.jasperreports.export.accessibility.tag" property
if so I marked this

In the exportElements(Collection elements) method I check if we are in a table and if so I swapped the text, x and width values of the left and right elements (for example if we have 4 elements, than I swap element at index 0 with that in index 3 and element at index 1 with the element at index 2

by doing this the order of the tags (witch dictates the read aloud order) is different then the drawing order (witch dictates how it is seen in the pdf)